# Sort the files by size either ascending/descending

Tags: c#, linq

Here from the directory i just selected the today's txt files, while sorting the files by size default file size are in ascending order. how to mention the preferred order

```
 DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(dir);

  var Files = info.GetFiles("*.txt")
                       .Where(p => p.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today)
                       .OrderByDescending(p => p.Length);
```

Comment: what issue you are getting? please update your question to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var sorted = Directory.GetFiles("*.txt").Where(p => p.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today).OrderBy(p => new FileInfo(p).Length);
```

Comment: there gotta be a duplicate for that, I just cannot image that such a question has never been asked once in those "1,375,921 questions" C# tagged